# Changing a Part of a variable within ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I want to evaluate nested do as a parallel computations. My formula looks like:

```
Do[
 Do[
  CC[[i, j]] += Kepf[[i, j]],{j, 1, Dimensions[Kepf][[2]]}
  ],{i, 1, Dimensions[Kepf][[1]]}
 ]
```

When previously I created 0 matrix CC and some matrix Kepf. I just want to insert matrix Kepf into matrix CC. 
When the matrices are very large it takes some time. So I want use parallel computations to shorten time.

Let`s consider a numerical example:

I create matrix A:

```
A = Table[0, {4}, {4}]
```

`{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}`

and matrix B:

```
B = Table[2 i + j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

then I evaluate the code

```
Do[A[[j]][[i]] += B[[i]][[j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
{{3, 5, 0, 0}, {4, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

I`ve got what I wanted, but when I try to do parallel computing using the code

```
SetSharedVariable[A, B]
ParallelDo[A[[j]][[i]] += B[[i]][[j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
```

It says that:

```
(kernel 2) Part::wrsym: Symbol A is Protected.
(kernel 1) Part::wrsym: Symbol A is Protected.
(kernel 2) Part::wrsym: Symbol A is Protected.
(kernel 1) Part::wrsym: Symbol A is Protected.
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can add matrices in Mathematica. `CC += Kepf;` should be much faster.

Comment: Yes I know, but these are not the same dimension matrices so it is not possible.

Comment: Then use `CC[[;;dimx,;;dimy]] += Kepf;` where dimx and dimy are the dimensions of `Kepf`. Under no circumstance should you be adding matrices using `Do`. You can also use `ArrayPad` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
a = Table[0, {4}, {4}]
b = Table[2 i + j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
```

using

```
SetSharedVariable[a]
ParallelDo[a[[j, i]] += b[[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
a
```

> ```
> {{3, 5, 0, 0}, {4, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

would work, but using

```
a += Transpose[b] ~PadRight~ Dimensions@a
```

> ```
> {{3, 5, 0, 0}, {4, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

is much nicer and faster.